# How to make Exchange 2013 Mail Apps only display in OWA

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-2013

I've built an Exchange 2013 mail app intended to add a subset of functionality from my outlook addin to OWA. The OWA side works fine, but the app also shows up in Outlook 2013, where it is redundant and non-functional. Is there a way to make mail apps only show up on OWA?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Microsoft doesn't want us to do things like this-see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/13c3413d-7f3f-4e7c-9b6d-c20e95b064e3/how-to-enable-mailapp-only-for-owaoutlookwebapp-not-for-outlook-client?forum=appsforoffice). There isn't any proper, supported way to do this<del>, but I was able to hack around it by taking advantage of a regex incompatibility between OWA and Outlook described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142267.aspx). That documentation looks like it's mistaken-Outlook doesn't support look-ahead regexes, and neither Outlook nor OWA support look-behind. That said, it looks like this rule activates the mail app in OWA but not in Outlook:
`<Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="SenderSMTPAddress" RegExName="BlockOutlook" RegExValue="(?=@)." />`</del>

It looks like Microsoft has "fixed" this incompatibility and the above method no longer works.